# Default logon-Domain for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, wss

When running Sharepoint (WSS 3.0) with Windows Authentication (NTLM), external users must supply their usernames in the form of *DOMAIN\username*. This makes sense, because you could have multiple domains, trusts between them, etc. However in my case, I only have one domain, and I want my users to be able to logon with their pure username only. Is there any way to configure Sharepoint with a default logon-Domain to get this to work?

Changing the authentication to basic or forms is not an option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a windows/IIS issue rather than something specific to sharepoint.

You can find a more detailed explanation at http://forums.iis.net/t/1151401.aspx but basically it's impossible due to the the design of integrated authentication - the client has to know the domain before the server is contacted.

The closest you get to a default domain is local logins on the server - potentially a solution if users are truly external.

Answer (score 2):

Realize that some browsers can be configured to automatically provide NTLM credentials.  For example, IE can do this.  I believe by default it will for sites in the Local Intranet and maybe even for Trusted sites (if not, you can change it so it will).

There is software out there for pushing these settings (policies) out to users if their computer is a part of your domain.